# Getting a value from a different class in django

Tags: django, django-models

As new to both Python and Django I have encounterd what I think is a simple problem, but which does not want to go away. I have a "table" with factors obtained from

```
class TjgFaktor(models.Model):
    typ = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    factor = models.FloatField()
```

Next I have another class which is foreign-keyed to this:

```
class Moment(models.Model):
    typ = models.ForeignKey(TjgFaktor,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

Now, what I want to do is to get the factor from the first class as an attribut to Moment. I have tried

```
def factor(self):
    return TjgFaktor.objects.get(typ=self).factor
```

in the hope of getting the correct factor. However, when I do something like

```
person_moment = Moment.objects.all()    
for e in person_moment:
    print(e.factor())
```

what I get is "TjgFaktor matching query does not exist".

So how should I do this? I guess it is the function: it works if I replace type=self with pk=1.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to obtain the `TjgFaktor` through an *explicit* query. If you query for `some_moment.typ`, Django itself will perform an implcit query to fetch the `TjgFaktor` that corresponds to the `Moment` (through the foreign key), or `None`, if the foreign key is set to `None`.

We can thus query like:

```
def factor(self):
    tjgfaktor = self.typ
    if tjgfaktor:
        return tjgfaktor.factor
```

In case there is no related `TjgFaktor`, then this function will return `None` as well.

In case you define a large amount of values, then this fetch might be inefficient: Django will fetch *all* columns from the database, and since we are only interested in a single one, this will thus result in some overhead.

We can avoid that by using the following query:

```
def factor(self):
    if self.typ_id:
        return (TjgFaktor.objects.values_list('factor', flat=True)
                                 .get(pk=self.typ_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `factor` is function within `Moment` class, you can access factor if `Moment` object has related `TjgFaktor` object:

```
def factor(self):
    return self.typ.factor if self.typ else None
```

Comment: Was it that simple! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So, the in the factor method, you need to enter the value for typ as a string value like this: A self does not satisfy the conditions of a string parameter that is required. You could do something like this -

```
def factor(self):
    return TjgFaktor.objects.get(typ="YOUR_TYPE_IN_STRING").factor
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def factor(self):
      return TjgFaktor.objects.get(typ=self).factor
```

You can't actually compare the object of **Moment** with objects in **TjgFaktor**. You can directly access the values of parent model or foreignkey directly by doing like this.

```
e.typ.factor #this will directly give you factor values of foreign key.
```

Or you can compare with

```
 def factor(self):
        return TjgFaktor.objects.get(typ=self.typ.id).factor
```